# Django can not find static files

Tags: django, django-templates

I am a beginner of django. I read documentation and other lot of answers. But, unfortunately can't figure out the problem. I am using django 1.4 and development server.

This is how my css and img file linked in the html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{ STATIC_URL }}style.css />
 <img src={{ STATIC_URL }}1.gif />
```

my directory settings:

```
 project
    -manage.py
    -project
    -app
        -static
        -models.py
        -views.py
        -tests.py
```

my settings file:

```
  STATIC_ROOT = ''
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
  STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
 )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your STATIC_ROOT to the path to your static directory based on your operating system. 
Django doesn't know in which directory to find your static files.

For example:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/project/app/static/'
```

From Django docs:

```
STATIC_URL : URL to use when referring to static files located in STATIC_ROOT.
```